# Resource for understanding mathematics behind multi-arm bandits

Tags: probability-theory, proof-writing, book-recommendation

I have been recently trying to understand the proofs related to convergence and regret analysis of multi-arm bandits. These proofs seem to use a variety of mathematical skills such as measure theory, sampling statistics, convergence bounds, etc.

I am trying to understand papers like

1. http://proceedings.mlr.press/v23/agrawal12/agrawal12.pdf
2. http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/auer02a/auer02a.pdf
3. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.1909.pdf
4. http://www.economics.uci.edu/~ivan/asmb.874.pdf

I know probability and statistics basics upto under-grad level. However, I am facing difficulty in completely understanding their proofs. Any resource such book, or course I should know before understanding these proofs would be highly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: If understanding proofs in general is something you have trouble with, I think you will benefit from studying some predicate logic and predicate deduction.

Comment: @shredalert No, I can understand the logic behind proofs. It is the concept used at someplaces that alludes me.